# jQuery ajax or load is returning empty results

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am working on a site that is using Wordpress and Xcart.  I am trying to make an ajax request from the WP part to grab contents from the Xcart shop.  It is all same domain but I am not having any luck with this.  If I try something simple or a full ajax request I am seeing the same issue.  For example with `.load()` I try something like :

```
$('#result').load('//site.com/store .image');
```

I see in firebug it makes the request twice.  The first time it returns a `301 Moved Permanently` error.  Then on the second request it returns a `200 OK` but the response is empty.  I have tried many, many ways to make this request but it is always coming up empty.  I imagine this is some issue with how the server is configured?  I know there are a million similar questions to this on SO and I have tried many of the solutions but nothing seems to apply to what ever is happening on this site.  Thanks in advance for any suggestions on how to fix.

UPDATE :

I am pretty certain this has something to do with xcart as if I try to load some other simple html page this way it works fine.   One thing I noticed is that in the response headers the desired page returns this:

Cache-Control   private, must-revalidate

Could this have anything to do with it?  I would just remove it to test but I cant find where it is being called from at the moment and I dont know if this really has anything to do with anything.. just fishing...

I tried wiping the .htaccess to see if that did anything but no go.

Comment: What happens when you copy the request URL from firebug and put it in the browser? Does it serve it properly?

Comment: Sorry if these are dumb questions, but 1) why are you passing a double-slash at the start of the URL and 2) do you mean to have a space character in the URL (i.e., 'store .image')? Do you really need to passing '/site.com/store%20.image'?

Comment: @dgvid with load() you can parse the resuting html with a selector. this means that he is trying to gett all elements with class 'image' from that page

Comment: `//site.com/` allows the browser to figure out if the external link is https or http.

Comment: @JohnP yes the url serves fine otherwise

Comment: @dgvid yes the // is because I am going from an http page to an https page.  The https page will render either way though.

Answer (score 0):

I know this may sound dumb, but are you sure you have elements with class `image` in the page that you load?
And are you sure that the page `http://site.com/load` is accessible from your browser?
Because your code seems ok, it's just the path that it's strange
in any case try using:

```
$('#result').load('/store .image');
```

to load the page (since it's on the same domain it should be the same thing)

Comment: yes i tried many things.. my quick example was just to get my point across.  i tried doing a full html response and tried using .ajax instead of load.  I should at least be able to see a response in firebug but there is nothing.